# Python: wrong assignment of default argument in a function

Tags: python

I have the following Python function which is definying a method of a class:

```
def SomeMethods(self,j=0)
```

According to the Python documentation, if any argument **j** is assigned when the function is called the default value of it should be 0. However, the variable j assumes the boolean value "True" (checked out in Debug session and actually raising an error because the value "True" goes to the index of a list). 
What can this problem be due to?

The call is executed when a button on a PyQt GUI is toggled, and the connection between the button and the function is made here:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(checkBox,QtCore.SIGNAL("toggled(bool)"),self.SomeMethods)
```

Comment: how did you debug it ? share some more code with us

Comment: Could you provide a reference for that part of the Python documentation, please?

Comment: By the way, you CAN use True to index a list if the list has at least 2 elements.  :)

Comment: @greole, I'm debugging with Aptana Studio 3.0 and if I could have shared some code I would have done it already.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ how can you not have any code? You must have an example of it happening *in some code*. Post that, and the result.

Comment: To get a better idea for the answerer, it's good to write the call to the function here.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ If there's no shareable code, then I can't see how you can expect an answer :)

Comment: @win of course, here is the [reference] (http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/defaultArgs.html). Yes I know, but the problem is that j = 0 has to get the default value exactly when the list is still containing only one element! Thanks anyway

Comment: Guys, I have not shareable code because the method is part of a 20k lines PyQt4 interface that, apart for being huge to be shared here (and I swear it doesn't work standing alone), it's also a job protected by security terms. Come on, wouldn't I have shared if I could? The only answer I was expecting is if it might be any wrong attribution from my side or if the problem might be due to any other reason, exactly as one guy just replied me telling me that it's for sure due to a call with the value True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

default argument is useful - among other cases - because it allows you to omit most common values used in your code. If you provide the actual value - that value will be used instead of default. Obviously, the method is called with argument *True*

**EDIT**:

Let me clarify - you may call your method either as *SomeMethods()* - and then *j* will be 0 inside the method; if you call it as *SomeMethods(True)* or *SomeMethods(j=True)*, then *j* value will be *True*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) So, it has to be a call with a default value True? What it sounds strange is that anyway in my code the function is called it just calls with no arguments. So, I was rather expecting either I'm giving the default argument wrong (but apparently not) or the j = 0 was for some reason passing as boolean rather than integer. How do you think it could be called with argument True, if anywhere the function has arguments yet?

Comment: how would you feel this connection (that will make the call when the button is pressed) might give j = True rather than j = 0? `QtCore.QObject.connect(checkBoxPNL,QtCore.SIGNAL("toggled(bool)"),self.SomeMethods)`

Comment: @MatteoNNZ, I presume that pressing button causes a call to someMethods() with the argument set to *True* (makes sense - status of the button is pressed, hence _True_ ). Since you connect it to a button, I think you do not need default value. BTW, feel free to accept my answer :) - if it satisfies you

Comment: Found the problem! As you were saying, being the call not done with someMethods() but just someMethods the default value it was taking was the one of the connection toggled(bool). I just needed to add the brackets not to pass that value. Thanks for solving my problem and especially to have answered with patience and precision although the broadness of my question due to the fact I cannot post the code here :)

Answer (score 2):

Please, share your code. See below - it works fine:

```
def SomeMethods(self, j=0):
    print j

SomeMethods('a')
0
SomeMethods('a', True)
True
```

Comment: Thanks mate, but exactly with the same structure is not working for me :/ I'd like to share some code if I could, but it's part of a very huge and privacy-protected PyQt GUI and the method itself doesn't work alone (you would need to have all the calls that are the parts I cannot share). But thanks for the example, it clarified me it has to be a wrong call rather than a wrong assignment. Vote up :)

Comment: you are welcome. One tip, maybe it would be helpful for you: check def func(*name)/def func(**name) calls - where args aren't specified explicitly.

Comment: how would you feel this connection (that will make the call when the button is pressed) might give j = True rather than j = 0? `QtCore.QObject.connect(checkBox,QtCore.SIGNAL("toggled(bool)"),self.SomeMeth‌ods)`